# Simperium Shared Common Data Set

Tags: ios, simperium

Im interested in using Simperium on iOS6 to share a common set of data across multiple users and at the same time each user to have their own unique data too.

Is this possible?

I was considering having 2 data sets one connecting to the unique user account and then one connecting a common, shared account .....

What do you think !?

Answer (score 0):

Common data for multiple users isn't yet possible in the production release of Simperium. Sharing and collaboration are currently being tested and will work in much the same way as device syncing.

Comment: Would this not work with multiple NSManagedObjectContexts, and why not?

Comment: Any update on multiple users? The Simperium website says: "Multiple users can collaborate with the same data at the same time", and yet as far as I can tell this is still not possible. Presumably it is still in private testing?

Comment: To answer your first question, you could in theory have two Simperium instances configured differently but that's going to become quite unwieldy. My suggestion would be to wait for full support for this, but unfortunately there's no timeline just yet. We're working to publish a roadmap soon though.

Comment: Any further update on collaboration (common data for multiple users)? Simplenote supports this, so presumably it's just a question of opening this up to any Simperium app?